# Unity3D character not moving in the direction its facing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two scripts: one for my player movement and another for my mouse-look.
The problem is that when I look in a direction my player moves in another.

Here is my Mouse Look Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
// Mouse Direction
private Vector2 mD;

private Transform myBody;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    myBody = this.transform.parent.transform;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    // How much has the mouse moved?
    Vector2 mC = new Vector2 (Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));

    mD += mC;

    this.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-mD.y, Vector3.right);

    myBody.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(mD.x, Vector3.up);
     }
}
```

Here is my player movement script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
Vector3 moveVector = Vector3.zero;
CharacterController characterController;

public float MoveSpeed;
public float JumpSpeed;
public float Gravity;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    moveVector.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * MoveSpeed;
    moveVector.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * MoveSpeed;

    if (characterController.isGrounded && Input.GetButton("Jump"))
    {
        moveVector.y = JumpSpeed;
    }

    moveVector.y -= Gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    characterController.Move(moveVector * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I am new to unity, so if you do know the answer I would appreciate it if you would explain it :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review [ask]. Be as specific as possible about what is currently happening and the code responsible (e.g. what do you mean by "player moves in another"?).

Answer (score 0):

One way to quickly fix what you have is to multiply your `moveVector` by the rotation of the player:

```
characterController.Move(transform.rotation * moveVector * Time.deltatime);
```

This will rotate your vector by the rotation of the player making it point in the same direction.

Another way to do this would be to use `transform.forward` and `transform.right`:

```
float moveX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * MoveSpeed;
float moveZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * MoveSpeed;

movementVector = (transform.forward * moveZ) + (transform.right * moveX);
```

`transform.forward` gets the forward vector of your object so you can use it to make sure the character moves forward on its forward.

Comment: thanks for your answer but it doesnt seem to work?

Comment: which solution are you doing?

Comment: im doing the first one

Comment: What's the problem? Is it going in random directions?

Comment: when i look right, the player moves forward because it doesnt know it has a mouse look script. for example i look at the x direction, the player thinks that im still looking in the z direction so when i press forward even though im looking in the x direction, it still goes z

Comment: If that happens, you can just switch the `moveZ` and `moveX` and set `movementVector = (transform.forward * moveX) + (transform.right * moveZ);`. This will make it so the character will go the other direction when you click the forward button.